# Setting Search Texfield Text Colour from UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar

I have used this piece of code to set Text Color for the Texfield Inside the UISearchBar.

```
for (UIView* view in subViews)
    {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField* searchTextField = (UITextField*)view;
            [self setTextColorToTextField:searchTextField];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (id view1 in view.subviews)
            {
                if ([view1 isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                {
                    UITextField* searchTextField = (UITextField*)view1;
                    [self setTextColorToTextField:searchTextField];
                    break;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to improve the code?

Comment: It is unclear what you need help with and what the problem you are facing.
I would recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no need to code when you can set its colour in the StoryBoard.

Here add this line in identity inspector of searchBar.

[image]